# How to show image outside inkcanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I have canvas called "drawCanvas" to show images and inkcanvas that is contained in the canvas called "CanvasContainInkCanvas". I can zoom out by using MatrixTransform.

```
//Get the image that's being manipulation.
Canvas element = (Canvas)e.Source;
 //Ues the matrix of the transform to manipulation the element's appearance.
Matrix matrix = ((MatrixTransform)drawCanvas.RenderTransform).Matrix;
//Get the ManipulationDelta object.
ManipulationDelta deltaManipulation = e.DeltaManipulation;
//Find the old center, and apply any previous manipulations.
Point center = new Point(element.ActualWidth / 2, element.ActualHeight / 2);
//Apply new move manipulation (if it exists).
center = matrix.Transform(center);
 //Apply new zoom manipulation (if it exists).
matrix.ScaleAt(deltaManipulation.Scale.X, deltaManipulation.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y);
//Translation (pan) 
matrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X, e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
//Set the final matrix.
((MatrixTransform)drawCanvas.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix;
// set the matrix of canvas that contain inkcanvas
((MatrixTransform)CanvasContainInkCanvas.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix;
```

If I zoom out, I can see images outside canvas.
[image]

I want to copy images from canvas to inkcanvas to use selection.
My problem is that the images cannot be shown outside inkcanvas.

[image]

How do I show images outside inkcanvas?

Thanks

**Update:** How do I use selection outside inkcanvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ClipToBounds="False"` on that `InkCanvas`. By default it's set to `True`.

Comment: Ok, I can show images now but I have new problem. How do I use selection outside inkcanvas?

Comment: What do you mean by `Selection outside InkCanvas`?